# Isotope Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create sortable menu by using isotope. 
Long story short:

```
        <script scr="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            // Active isotope with JQuery code
            $(".main-iso").isotope({
                itemSelector: ".item",
                layoutMode: "fitRows"
            });

            // Click function

            $(".iso-nav ul li").click(function() {
                $(".iso-nav ul li").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");

                var selector = $(this).attr("data-filter");
                $(".main-iso").isotope({
                    filter: selector
                });
                return false;
            });
        </script>
```

On line 4 i get **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**.

Here is HTML

```
<div class="wraper">
                    <div class="iso-nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active" data-filter="*">All items</li>
                            <li data-filter=".web">Web Design</li>
                            <li data-filter=".graphic">Graphic Design</li>
                            <li data-filter=".photo">Photography</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="main-iso">
                        <div class="item web"><img src="imagestest/ko1.jpg" alt="1"></div>
                        <div class="item graphic"><img src="imagestest/ko1.jpg" alt="2"></div>
                        <div class="item photo"><img src="imagestest/ko1.jpg" alt="3"></div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how I can make this jQuery code work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get error in line 5, sorry

Comment: `scripts/jquery.js` should be an external google jQuery URL, so it's cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that jQuery is undefined.

On your line `<script scr="scripts/jquery.js"></script>`, you are stating that jQuery is in a folder called `scripts` at the **same level** as the page you are including it on.

This could be simply that you have forgotten to include it in the project, but it's more likely that you referenced it incorrectly. Depending on where your `jquery.js` file actually resides, you will need to change this reference.

- You can use the **relative link** `../` to navigate up one folder.
- You can use the **root-relative link** `/scripts/jquery.js` to always reference the root.
- You can use the **absolute link** `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js` to load a hosted version of jQuery from the CDN.

For further reading on relative and absolute URLs, I recommend checking out this **[Coffee Cup article](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: <script scr=https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script> I also thought that it is the most obvious way but still nothing

Comment: <script scr="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> that how it looks, not working :(

Comment: It's `src`, not `scr`. You also need the protocol (`https://` or `http://`) ...or the protocol-agnostic `src="://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"`. You're **probably** simply looking for `src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"`.

Comment: You should absolutely use https. No reason at all not to. If you don't, browsers will give insecure content warnings or block it if your page is served over https. No reason to use http in 2017.

Comment: http was there, it jus did not get copied in comment section somehow, and *yes* you are right about this damn typo, sorry for that. Now I have no error indeed, thank you but grid system is not working anyway

Comment: That is true, and there's more information regarding that at https://doesmysiteneedhttps.com/. However, there are plenty of legacy systems around, and setting up HTTPS can be a little much for someone just starting out :)

Answer (score 0):

The two .js files haven't loaded when your code is executed. Hence why $ is still undefined. If you move the

```
<script src=...>
```

tags into the document's head, they will block further javascript from running until they've loaded.

Comment: If you've already got the script tags in your head, Obsidian is probably right about it being a bad link.

Comment: all <script> tags are in the head section